# Sharing internet from wired desktop to ad-hoc notebook

Tags: networking, internet, ubuntu-gnome, adhoc

First of all, I show my scenario:

I have a wired desktop-pc with Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04 and a laptop with the same OS. The ad-hoc mode works fine in my laptop, but not in my desktop (may be drivers).

Anyway, I want to connect my laptop to internet through my desktop-pc but using my laptop as ap (or in ad-hoc mode).

There's a way to connect my desktop to my laptop, using my laptop as hotspot, to share with the laptop the wired internet in my desktop? (sorry by the tongue twister)

**NOTES:**

1. Both, my desktop and my laptop, have a WiFi card
2. My desktop CAN'T BE a hotspot (because of drivers trouble)
3. My desktop has a wired internet connection
4. My laptop can be a hotspot
5. I need internet in my laptop

Comment: So you want to connect your desktop to your laptop's WiFi hotspot and share the desktop's LAN connection over this WiFi network? Yes, this is possible, but only if your desktop happens to have a WiFi card in it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yes, my desktop have a WiFi card ;)

Comment: So can you not see the interface, can you not connect to the laptop's network or can you not see any networks?

Comment: @Zacharee1 When I turn on the ad-hoc mode in my laptop I can connect my desktop to the laptop, but I can't navigate using the laptop.

Comment: You need to share the LAN connection over the WiFi connection, and the only way to do this might be to make the hotspot on the desktop.

Comment: Unless he wants to connect the desktop to the laptop who has WiFi Internet access...  Then he needs to use a cross-cable.  @Zacharee1  (unclear to me)

Comment: @Fabby the desktop has the internet connection, which is why I'm unsure of why the hotspot has to be hosted on the laptop, when the desktop has wired internet.

Comment: @Zacharee1, I can't use my desktop as hotspot, it doesn't works (it could be a trouble with drivers) but my laptop can be a hostspot. My question is about it: can I connect my desktop to my laptop, using my laptop as hotspot, to share with the laptop the wired internet in my desktop? (sorry by the tongue twister)

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but you could check the options. There might be something to, instead of using DHCP, use the WiFi adapter as the sharing destination. I wish I had an Ubuntu machine to use, because I do sort of know where this option might be, but I can't describe it well. Let me make a VM and I'll get back to you.

Comment: OK. Check this image. Apply it to your WiFi card and hopefully it'll work. Otherwise we need to figure out why your desktop can't make a hotspot. http://i.imgur.com/ZtjrY5u.png